# Why does leading slash not match my RewriteRule?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, openshift

I hope I'm missing something silly.

I'm trying to redirect URLs using .htaccess on Apache 2.2 using the PHP 5.4 cartridge on OpenShift's free hosting service.

This matches the URI /permalink/a123 (note the lack of leading slash in the rule's filter pattern):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule permalink/a.*$ /permalink/b [R=301,L]
```

This does not match the URI /permalink/a123 (note the leading slash in the rule's filter pattern):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /permalink/a.*$ /permalink/b [R=301,L]
```

So what stupid thing do I have wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I've checked: ^permalink/a.*$ matches, but ^/permalink/a.*$ doesn't match. Could it be that OpenShift's PHP 5.4 cartridge is stripping leading slashes on me and not telling me? I haven't found any configuration file that includes any such directives, but maybe I don't know where to look.

Comment: The starting slash is implied. If you want it to be changed you would use `RewriteBase /` to change the base location from which the rule applies.

Comment: Use /permalink/(.*)$

Comment: Starting slash is stripped in `RewriteRule` (if used in .htaccess)

Comment: <code>RewriteBase /</code> looks like the difference between this .htaccess file which behaves contrary to my (now old) expectations and an .htaccess file on another server that behaves the way I used to expect. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URI used to match patterns in a `RewriteRule` are canonicalized in a per-directory context (either in an htaccess file or in a `<Directory>` container) by removing the leading `/`. So if the requested URL is:

```
http://example.com/web/permalink/123
```

And from within an htaccess file in the document root, the URI used to match rules is `web/permalink/123`. But within an htaccess file in the `web` folder, the URI is `permalink/123`, etc.

Thus you can't have your patterns start with a `/` because they're stripped from the URI in the context of an htaccess file.

Comment: This all makes sense, but it doesn't explain why I have another .htaccess in the Document Root that matches patterns with the leading slash.

I now see one difference mentioned elsewhere here: <code>RewriteBase /</code>. I have this directive in the .htaccess file in the Document Root that matches URIs with the leading slash. I assume that that's the crucial information I was missing.

That said, I think I understand why I ought not to use the leading slash in these URI patterns.

Comment: @J.B.Rainsberger The `RewriteBase` directive doesn't affect the leading slash in the rewrite rule's *pattern*, it affects the rule's target (it appends the base to relative targets). The difference is probably a `RewriteRule /foo` vs `RewriteRule ^/foo`. The first matches **any** `/foo` anywhere in the URI, the second has a `^` and matches only the beginning of the URI, and will fail because the beginning doesn't have a `/`.

Comment: Crystal clear. Thanks. I think I finally understand.